# Stored procedure : how to return a decimal in EF and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, isnull

I created a stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(p.Amount), 0.00)
FROM 
    Payments p
LEFT JOIN 
    TenantTenancies tt ON tt.TenancyId = p.TenancyId
INNER JOIN 
    Tenant t ON t.Id = tt.TenantId
WHERE 
    t.UserId = @UserId 
    AND p.IsTenant = 1 
    AND p.Date < @StartDate
```

What I want it to do in ASP.NET MVC is to return a `decimal`, however it keeps returning an `INT`, how do I make it return a `decimal`? Is it a problem with the SQL or the ASP.NET MVC side?

I know I can use scalar `decimal`, however this turns it into an `ObjectResult(Decimal)` I would just like it to return a `decimal` or `decimal?`. If I click returns a collection of NONE, it just default goes to a `int` yet it works on the page fine without issues its just I want it to return the correct value 24.45 for example.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the issue is: how could EF know that you're only returning a **single** `decimal`? A stored procedure returns a **result set** - potentially any number of rows, any number of columns.

So that's why you're getting an `ObjectResult<decimal?>`. If **you** know that this will only ever contain a single row with a single decimal - then just use `.SingleOrDefault`, and if this returns something other than null - you have your result:

```
ObjectResult<decimal?> results = ctx.GetDecimal();

if (result != null)
{
    decimal? theResult = result.SingleOrDefault();

    if(theResult != null)
    {
       decimal resultValue = theResult.Value;
    }
}
```